# Input field character sequence

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

Input Field to follow and check for the following algorithm. Maximum 11 alpha-numeric characters:

1. 1st to 4th characters => Alphabetic characters- no numbers and special characters.
2. 5th characters => 0 (Just a single Zero)
3. 6th to 11th Characters => Alpha-numeric.

I think my question is quite simple, i want to enter 11 characters in an input field but first 4 characters should be as defined in point 1 and 5th character should be 0 and 6th characters to onward alphanumeric . input field should allow to enter characters as i defined , if some one want to enter 1 or other character at 5ht positions input field should not allow because 5ht position is for 0 and same expressions for other positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to use `regex`:

```
$('input').val().match(/^[a-z]{4}0[a-z0-9]{6}$/i);
```

1. `^` : Starts with
2. `[a-z]` : Allows Alphabetic characters
3. `{4}`: Matches 4 preceding characters
4. `0` : Matches `0`
5. `[a-z0-9]`: Matches any characters from a-z and 0-9 in any sequence
6. `$`: End of string
7. `i`: Case insensitive match

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex to do this.

```
/^[a-z]{4}0[\w]{6}$/
```

Demo: **https://regex101.com/r/cK1sO4/1**

Answer (score 0):

To check value in case sensitive use this regex.

/^[a-zA-Z]{4}0[\w]{6}$/